# Unable to enable VI input-line editing mode in Ubuntu 20.04 mysql cli 8

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-20.04

I installed mysql cli 8.0.21 in my ubuntu 20.04 instance, `ldd /usr/bin/mysql` indicates it is linked with libedit:

```
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe288df000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f03f5830000)
        libedit.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libedit.so.2 (0x00007f03f57f8000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f03f57dc000)
        libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f03f5749000)
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f03f5473000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f03f546d000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f03f528a000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f03f526f000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f03f507d000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f03f5f69000)
        libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007f03f504d000)
        libbsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f03f5033000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f03f4ee4000)
```

According to [mysql Client Tips](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tips.html#mysql-input-editing) I should be able to enable VI input-line editing mode by adding a `~/.editrc` with these settings:

```
bind -v
```

This doesn't work unfortunately.

I also have an Ubuntu 18.04 box which has mysql 5 installed, in this setup I can use `~/.editrc` to enable VI mode.

So how to troubleshoot this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libedit/+bug/1921484